# Abort crash "/system/lib64/libhwui.so"

Tags: android

Google Play Console is showing abort crashes, the stack trace is the following:

> backtrace:
> #00  pc 000000000004e40c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164)
> #00  pc 000000000004b10c  /system/lib64/libc++.so (abort_message+248)
> #00  pc 000000000004b2d0  /system/lib64/libc++.so (demangling_terminate_handler()+212)
> #00  pc 000000000004bdc4  /system/lib64/libc++.so (std::__terminate(void (*)())+12)
> #00  pc 000000000004b4e0  /system/lib64/libc++.so (__cxxabiv1::failed_throw(__cxxabiv1::__cxa_exception*)+28)
> #00  pc 000000000004b448  /system/lib64/libc++.so (__cxa_throw+112)
> #00  pc 000000000004ebb4  /system/lib64/libc++.so (operator new(unsigned long)+96)
> #00  pc 0000000000098244  /system/lib64/libc++.so (std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >::__grow_by_and_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*)+156)
> #00  pc 0000000000098148  /system/lib64/libc++.so (std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >::append(char const*, unsigned long)+100)
> #00  pc 00000000000105ec  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::ReadFdToString(android::base::borrowed_fd, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >*)+192)
> #00  pc 00000000000106ec  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::ReadFileToString(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >*, bool)+192)
> #00  pc 0000000000046e9c  /system/lib64/libunwindstack.so (unwindstack::Maps::Parse()+112)
> #00  pc 000000000000e5f4  /system/lib64/libbacktrace.so (UnwindStackMap::Build()+532)
> #00  pc 000000000000ea8c  /system/lib64/libbacktrace.so (BacktraceMap::Create(int, bool)+128)
> #00  pc 00000000005c1b24  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits >&, bool)+236)
> #00  pc 000000000055ce40  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1864)
> #00  pc 0000000000013978  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76)
> #00  pc 0000000000006e18  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+336)
> #00  pc 00000000002154e4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::swapBuffers(android::uirenderer::renderthread::Frame const&, bool, SkRect const&, android::uirenderer::FrameInfo*, bool*)+172)
> #00  pc 000000000021e20c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+940)
> #00  pc 00000000002205f4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+480)
> #00  pc 000000000020ed9c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+220)
> #00  pc 0000000000230074  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+88)
> #00  pc 00000000000154cc  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+260)
> #00  pc 0000000000014d90  /system/lib64/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+412)
> #00  pc 00000000000b0048  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
> #00  pc 00000000000503c8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)

I couldn't reproduce this bug and didn't find information either.

This bug happens most of the time in Android 11

Anyone has an idea what thing fire this bug?.

Any information is appreciated. Thank you.